# rxjava handle callback in observable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-recyclerview, rx-android

I have a simple recyclerview that contains a custom ImageGLSurfaceView in which it shows a bitmap. If i had a simple imageview i would have used (Picasso or glide etc) for this easily. But i have ImageGLSurfaceView so i am trying to do is to mimic ImageLoader lib class. So i have ImageLoader class that has loadImage method which i call from recycler view's adapter and i cache/store ImageGLSurfaceView object in hashmap and handle it like below:

```
public void loadImage(final FilteredImage filteredImage, final ImageGLSurfaceView imageView) {
    if(images.containsKey(filteredImage)) {
        images.get(filteredImage).setImageBitmap(filteredImage.getBitmap());
        images.get(filteredImage).setFilterWithConfig(filteredImage.getFilter());
    } else {
        images.put(filteredImage, imageView);
        imageView.setSurfaceCreatedCallback(new ImageGLSurfaceView.OnSurfaceCreatedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated() {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(filteredImage.getBitmap());
                imageView.setFilterWithConfig(filteredImage.getFilter());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But list is slow or i think it is recreating ImageGLSurfaceView object again on list scroll. Or maybe i should put surfaceCreatedCallback on background thread. So i decided to use RxJava for this purpose. I want to subscribe for ImageGLSurfaceView to be created and once it is created then set Image bitmap and dont create ImageGLSurfaceView again. Please guide me if this is the right approach to achieve this? Or should i completely change the code?

Comment: I would firstly use [LRUCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class to store bitmaps, more important thing is to store images matching the size of your imageview and not complete bitmaps.
Read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html) article to efficiently handle bitmaps.
Also you will need a DiskLruCache along with inMemory cache. see [Disk LRU example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

Comment: Even better way would be to use an image loading library(Glide, Picasso etc.) and load the bitmap to a target class and set the bitmap to your view from the target class callback.

Comment: how i can use Picasso with ImageGLSurfaceView (other than ImageView) can you show an example?

Comment: see [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-callbacks-remoteviews-and-notifications)

Comment: the problem is i am not trying to load bitmap from anywhere (local or remote network) I already have a bitmap image taken from camera/gallery i will show the same bitmap on every list item, just need to apply different filter on same bitmap and show in recyclerview just like Instagram filters horiznotal list. So there is no need to use picasso because picasso will only help to load image that i already have.

Comment: I then hope you are storing thumbnails and main image separately. :)
effects can be applied to main image at runtime, and you can store only thumbnails in memory